# How react app updates the data in real time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

currently i have a requirement to manage the web application's data that follows certain hierarchy using a react app,every time data is submitted it needs to show the latest data on the page .I thought of saving the submitted form data locally in the react app and  add it to page every time I make POST request.if i do that,app may not reflect the exact data if multiple persons are simultaneously adding since they will only see what the have added each till they do complete page refresh.I am just wondering what should be good strategy while making react apps to always show the latest data as of server?

(1)do I need to use timers to do GET requests  to pull the latest data from server?
(2) or do I need to re issue relevant GET requests whose response may likely to change after every PUT,DELETE,POST request i do?

Comment: Use a websocket. When data is pushed to the server, emit the updated data down to any clients who may be listening.

Comment: I agree with @FrankerZ if webockets are out of reach then the best thing you can do is probably every time the user makes a change, don't use the restful API's return data on PUT, DELETE, POST. Use the GET call again after each request to get the new information from the server. That should give you enough confidence that users are looking at the most up to date information